# JS regex to find the first number at the beginning of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to perform a very simple task in JS, but coming from PHP, it's unknown territory for me...

So I need to extract the first number from a string. The string can be one of these:

```
180gr.
140gr. - 200gr.
unlimited food
```

So, in the above cases I want to extract 180 for the first string, 140 for the second, and an empty string for the third one.

In PHP, the command to do that would be `preg_match( '/^\d*/', $string, $matches );`.

Can someone help me figure out how to write this in JS?

Comment: What have you tried? The JS regex would look pretty similar... `const matches = str.match(/^\d*/)`

Comment: Straight forward: `const match = string.match(/^\d*/gm)`.

Comment: @InSync the `gm` flags are unnecessary. OP doesn't seem concerned about multi-line strings or global matches in their PHP example

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I assumed worst case in which there is a multiline string. That is also why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do the following:**

```js
const string1 = "180gr.";
const string2 = "140gr. - 200gr.";
const string3 = "unlimited food";

function matchRegex(string) {
  const pattern = /^\d*/;

  const matchedString = string.match(pattern)[0];
  return matchedString.length ? `Matched: ${matchedString}` : "No match found";
}
console.log(matchRegex(string1));
console.log(matchRegex(string2));
console.log(matchRegex(string3));
```

Here, in the pattern: `/^\d*/`:

`^`: Matches the beginning of the string

`\d`: Matches digits

`*`: Matches 0 or more of the preceding tokens

Note: If no match is found, a message is shown. [String:length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) is used to check the condition

Comment: In the case of string3, where it won't match anything, how can I catch that? Meaning that match3 is empty? I tried  `alert(match3==="");` and it returns false, so it's empty, but some other type of empty... How can I check that please?

Comment: @FayeD. `match3 === ""` returns `true` here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/nazx69vd/

Comment: You can check this with the .length property, I have updated the code to handle cases when no match is found, check my updated answer @FayeD.

Comment: I had forgotten to use the [0] index... So I was check it as an array? After putting [0] indeed it returns true in the case of unlimited food! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Following code will return the beginning number from a string:

```
const extractNumber = (text) => {
  const numberPattern = /^\d+/;
  const match = text.match(numberPattern);

  return match ? match[0] : ''
}
```

Comment: @Phil `'unlimited food'.match(/^\d+/) // null`

Comment: My mistake, I see you used `+` instead of `*`

Comment: @InSync I tried all possible combinations to check for the empty match in the case of "unlimited food" but I always get an alert false... I tried `alert(daily_portion == null || daily_portion.length === 0);` `alert(daily_portion === null);`, none gives me a true for the case of unlimited food, and I need to check that case. What am I missing here?

Comment: When you're unsure about something, print it out. Use `console.log(daily_portion)` and open your browser's Dev Tools to see its value. Also,note that this answer will return either the match or an empty string.